# Azure Websites PHP API - 500 Method Not Allowed on

Tags: php, api, azure

I just completed PHP API on local server, and it works perfectly. Now I tried to deploy it on Azure Web App but obtained an error during any get/post request, like:
[image]

Here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <location>
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="true" manyToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="false" logonMethod="ClearText">
                        <oneToOneMappings>
                            <clear />
                            <add userName="domain\user" password="pass" certificate="the certificate blob" />
                        </oneToOneMappings>
                        <manyToOneMappings>
                            <clear />
                        </manyToOneMappings>
                    </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
                <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
            </security>
            <defaultDocument enabled="true">
                <files>
                    <clear />
                    <add value="index.php" />
                    <add value="index.htm" />
                    <add value="index.html" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
                <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script"
                />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where did you see *"method not allowed"*?

Answer (score 3):

By default, PHP v5.3 is **not** available on Azure Web App. It may cause your problem. You could upgrade the PHP runtime to v5.5 or higher.

[image]

Replace your `handlers` configuration with the following. It should work.

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="PHP56_via_FastCGI" />
    <add name="PHP56_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

If you wish to continue to run PHP 5.3 in your Azure Web App, follow the steps in [How to: Use a custom PHP runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-use-a-custom-php-runtime) to explicitly set the PHP runtime of your site.

Comment: Thanks! I use PHP 7.1. So I had to replace 56 by 71 and 5.6 by 7.1 to make it work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450658/azure-app-service-with-php-enable-more-http-verbs